# Problems Deploying GWT Project

Tags: java, tomcat, fedora, gwt-rpc

trying to deploy gwt application with RPC service over tomcat in fedora, but its not connecting to the database while logging in. Although the same is working over tomcat in windows. Do we have to do something different in fedora? Problem is only with connection with the database, as while calling RPC service, no object is returned?

Comment: did you considered looking at your database permissions/access on fedora?

Comment: is there any problem with RPC's while deploying?

Comment: not really, just standard db permission caveats. What does the log files say?

Answer (score 1):

Is your JDBC driver working properly ? If not then run as root,

yum install mysql-connector-java

Also try testing with a simple java program.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Connect
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;

        try
        {
            String userName = "testuser";
            String password = "testpass";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close ();
                    System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```